# Building query string links

Tags: php, arrays, get, query-string, filtering

I'm building a filters section for my search page and I was wondering what is the best way to go about doing the query strings. My problem is that these links function a lot like checkboxes, so some, all or none can be on. I'd have to loop through each of about 30 or so links, removing or adding that specific link's value depending on its state.

My first concern is:

Should I pass the arrays like

```
colors=red,blue,green   //explode?
```

or

```
colors[]=red&colors[]=blue&colors[]=green   //parse_str?
```

What is the fastest/best way to remove a certain value of a certain array as I loop through each link? I imagine it'd be a bit more complicated using the second method I've posted above, yes?

**EDIT2 - What do you think of this?**

I've ran into a tutorial online and came up with this:

```
function remove( $filters = array(), $remove_key = NULL, $remove_val = NULL )
    {
        if( $remove_key != NULL && array_key_exists($remove_key,$filters) )
        {
            if( $remove_val != NULL && array_key_exists($remove_val,array_flip($filters[$remove_key])) )
            {
                $filters[$remove_key] = array_diff($filters[$remove_key],array($remove_val));
            } else {
                unset($filters[$remove_key]);
            }
        }
        return http_build_query( $filters );
    }
```

Currently, I can pass $remove_key to remove a key and $remove_val to remove a value from a key in an array.

What do you guys think? Would this be too slow for for doing 30-50 links? Thanks!

Comment: Note in your second example you don't have to call `parse_str`; PHP will populate `$_GET['colors']` with an array for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
 colors[]=red&colors[]=blue&colors[]=green
```

Would be a the Way a Form would submit the data (when method="get"). And you can access it via $_GET['colors'] which is the native and by that probably the fastest way.

EDIT: to get that string via `http_build_query` just fill them in the array color

```
$data = array('colors' => array('green','red','blue'));
echo http_build_query($data); // colors[0]=green&colors[1]=red&colors[2]=blue
```

Comment: +1: Not to mention that it doesn't require JavaScript to assemble.  And it's the most portable method (since all browsers should be able to handle it)...

Comment: colors[]=red&colors[]=blue&colors[]=green turns into 0=red&1=blue&2=green when I use http_build_query -- how can I rebuild the query string? (or even remove a value before rebuilding it?)

Comment: @RS7 i have extended my Answer, i hope it helps :)

Comment: I appreciate everybody's help so far ;) I'm having a hard time making a system to quickly/easily remove parts of an array before outputting the query strings again. I'm new to all of this but is there a function that finds values and deletes that array entry? I know I can do unset($array['key']) but what about values? Sorry - I'm quite new to all of this.